# Some mixin parameters remain unchanged when called with several values

Tags: javascript, css, less

I have a `.less` stylesheet that has a mixin for custom gradients. When I create several gradients with it, the rules for all other browsers come out fine but the `filter` for old IE browsers doesn't change after the first call.

Here is a stripped-down example I managed to replicate my problem with:

```
.myGradient(@bg: rbg(255,255,255), @start: #FFFFFF, @end: #E6E6E6) {
        background: @start;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @start 0%,@end 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr=@start, endColorstr=@end,GradientType=0 );
}

.one {
        .myGradient(#ffa201,#ffa201,#ff7301);
}

.two {
        .myGradient(#aaaaaa,#aaaaaa,#cccccc);
}

.three {
        .myGradient(#ffffff,#ffffff,#000000);
}
```

Here is the resulting CSS as generated by `lessc 1.3.0`:

```
.one {
  background: #ffa201;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffa201 0%, #ff7301 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffa201, endColorstr=#ff7301, GradientType=0);
}
.two {
  background: #aaaaaa;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aaaaaa 0%, #cccccc 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffa201, endColorstr=#ff7301, GradientType=0);
}
.three {
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #000000 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffa201, endColorstr=#ff7301, GradientType=0);
}
```

As you can see, the webkit gradient works as expected but the IE one always stays orange. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(StartColorStr='%d', EndColorStr='%d', GradientType=0)",@start,@end));
```

Comment: Yes, that did it, thank you! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. Why does that happen and what is the `e()` function - looks like some kind of `printf()` equivalent? I found nothing about it in the manual.

Comment: e() removes quotes in the same way as ~"". A more up-to-date way of doing this would be ~"progid:...StartColorStr='@{start}'"..". But to be honest this is a bug in less.js and you shouldn't need to do it at all.